# Codeigniter 4 - Cannot get my module to work

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am trying to get a simple module working.  All it does is echo 'test' to a web page but I cannot get it working.

The first thing I did was add the module to app/Config/Autoload.php as follows;

```
public $psr4 = [
    APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH, // For custom app namespace
    'Config'      => APPPATH . 'Config',
    'Modules\Filemanager' => ROOTPATH . 'modules'       
];
```

Then, I created the following directory structure;

[image]

In Modules/Filemanager/Config/Routes.php I have added following route;

```
<?php
$routes->add('/filemanager/(:any)', 'Modules\Filemanager\Controllers\Filemanager::index');
```

Lastly, in Modules/Filemanager/Controllers/Filemanager I have the following method:

```
<?php 
namespace Modules\Filemanager\Controllers;
use App\Controllers\BaseController;

class Filemanager extends \App\Controllers\BaseController
{
    public function index(){
        echo 'test'; die();
    }
}
```

When I go to my browser and enter example.com/filemanager/index I get the following error;

```
Controller or its method is not found: \App\Controllers\Filemanager::index
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You've done few things wrong here.

1. In the App/Config/Autoload.php,
   you've written 
    `'Modules\Filemanager' => ROOTPATH . 'modules'` 
   But in your directory structure image, there is no directory with the name 'modules'

   **Please change the 'Modules' folder name to 'modules'**
2. Change 
   **'Modules\Filemanager' => ROOTPATH . 'modules'** 
    to 
   **'Modules' => ROOTPATH . 'modules'**
    in App/Config/Autoload.php
3. In the Modules/Filemanager/Config/Routes.php
   You're using the $routes variable in the below line 
   `$routes->add('/filemanager/(:any)', 'Modules\Filemanager\Controllers\Filemanager::index');` 
    But $routes is not defined anywhere in the file.
   Put

   ```
    if(!isset($routes)) {
        $routes = App\Config\Services::routes(true);
    } 
    $routes->get('/filemanager/(:any)', 'Modules\Filemanager\Controllers\Filemanager::index');
   ```

   It should be $routes->get() instead of $routes->add()
4. Module level routing will not work until you add these routes in the App\Config\Routes.php file.
   To add your modules routes to the app\Config\Routes.php

```
  foreach(glob(ROOTPATH . 'modules/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $item_dir) {
    if(file_exists($item_dir . '/Config/Routes.php')) {
       require_once($item_dir . '/Config/Routes.php');
    }
  }
```

After these changes your code should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation.  I implemented above but I still get the same error.  I even specific the method like;  example.com/filemanager/index

Comment: I have gone through all my code again and believe it matches exactly as stated.  Just cannot seem to reach the controller

Comment: Can you please show the error that is coming?

Comment: It is the same error.  Controller or its method not found.

Comment: I also follow this and I get the same error as above.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUtQ5-6l4is

Comment: I changed the CI4 Routes.php to that of the youutube video mentioned above.  When I echo out the $routesPath it is correct;  /var/www/example.com/app_dir/modules/Filemanager/Config/Routes.php

Comment: Changed my module routes file to  $routes->get('/filemanager', 'Modules\Filemanager\Controllers\Filemanager::index');  Still same error

Comment: Changed module controller to class Filemanager extends \Codeigniter\Controller
{
    public function index(){
        echo 'test'; die();
    }
}
still same error

Comment: I do notice that when I do example.com/filemanager it redirects to example.com. When I do example.com/filemanager/index, I get the same error as before.

Comment: ok, I have a dir in public/filemanager. I removed it.  Now it gives error:  Controller or its method is not found: \App\Controllers\Modules\Filemanager\Controllers\Filemanager::index

Comment: @spreadman You need to read your error messages. Where is your Modules Folder located? Is it under \App\Controllers\Modules or under \Modules? You might need to add the leading \ So that Modules becomes \Modules so it knows where to look. Check your code where you reference it and be consistent .